# Can't save and close a XLS file in Access/VBA application correctly

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm quite new in Access and VBA and trying to develop a simple code: export a table to a xls, open it, simple manipulations(formatting), save and close.

But I'm getting the following message box during the process: `"A file named RESUME.XLW" already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?"`

Choosing "Yes" will generate the xls file. But when I try to open it, the Excel runs in read only mode, and I don't understanding why.

I'm using the following code:

```
Sub FormataExcelPadrao(caminhoExcel As String)

Set arquivoExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
arquivoExcel.Workbooks.Open (caminhoExcel)

With arquivoExcel
    For Each pagina In .Worksheets
        With pagina
            .Columns("A:Z").Autofit
            .Cells.Font.Size = "10"
            .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        End With
    Next pagina
End With

arquivoExcel.Save
arquivoExcel.Close

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your objects and then use it. See this example

```
Sub FormataExcelPadrao(caminhoExcel As String)
    Dim arquivoExcel As Object, wb As Object, pagina As Object

    Set arquivoExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = arquivoExcel.Workbooks.Open(caminhoExcel)

    With wb '<~~ Also this has to be the workbook and not excel app
        For Each pagina In .Worksheets
            With pagina
                .Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
                .Cells.Font.Size = "10"
                .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            End With
        Next pagina
    End With

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    arquivoExcel.Quit

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set arquivoExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams Dunno how did I miss that. Updated! Next time if you see any such silly mistakes, feel free to amend it :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 arquivoExcel.Save
```

With:

```
 arquivoExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

See: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1065376